# restriction of accessing the pages through URL in PHP?

Tags: php

I have php application in that, when user login to application then session started. In session i have stored user type and id. Using user type restrict the access of user pages like add.php, display.php, edit.php etc.

My problem is that the when user login to application that user type and id will be stored in session but when any user change in url like add.php. this page will be accessed by other user.

I want to do when user changes url then say some error message.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || !isset($_SESSION['login_type']) )
{
     header("Location:logout.php");
     exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to do? Do you want to prevent the user from going to another URL or what?

Comment: i just want to prevent unauthorized page access through url for same application.

Comment: If you have types of users, that some are allowed to use add.php and some don't, it's not enough just to check if session exists, check also the content of login_type

Comment: some user are allow to access the add.php thruogh link on home page but i dont want to access through changing of URL.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. How the user arrives at add.php does not matter. You need to check inside add.php if the current user is allowed to see that page or not.

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT** just use `isset`. That will only check whether the variable exists or not and it wont check what value that variable contains

So, you can include something like this in the function

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['login_type'] != 'Admin') )
{
     header("Location:logout.php"); //Do not allow him to access.
     exit;
}
```

First of all, when you will be creating a session create `session` variables that will be having `logintype` like `user,admin,superadmin`

And then create a general function to check the session. like

```
checkSession();
```

Put this function in a  file which you will `include` it
This function should be able to verify whether the user is authorized or not at the top, before even the file is processed and displayed.

Comment: i want to restrict the page access through url but not through the link on home page. from link that will be accessed but when user changes the url like edit.php then any user not access through the url.

Comment: In your edit.php page include the checksession function at the top, so even if user directly types the url,session will be checked at the top itself and he will be taken to the logout page